# Dynamic editing Content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, observablecollection

I have a MVVM application using 3 usercontrols as content in multiple pages (pages are also usercontrols) with some additional static content.

For example:

**Page1.xaml**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="pnlMain" Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Title 1" />
    <local:UserControl1 />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Title 2" />
    <local:UserControl2 />
    <local:UserControl2 />
</StackPanel>
```

**Page2.xaml**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="pnlMain" Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Title 3" />
    <local:UserControl2 />
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Title 4" />
    <local:UserControl3 />
</StackPanel>
```

Each usercontrol's `ViewModel` is binded to a `ObservableCollection` inside each page's `ViewModel`

For example:

**Page1ViewModel.cs**

```
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public ObservableCollection<UserControl1ViewModel> Ucon1
    {
        get { return this.ucon1; }
        set { this.ucon1= value; Changed("Ucon1"); }
    }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public ObservableCollection<UserControl2ViewMode> Ucon2
    {
        get { return this.ucon2; }
        set { this.ucon2= value; Changed("Ucon2"); }
    }
```

What i would like to accomplish is to be able to move (copy to page2 and remove from page1) a usercontrol between pages. I was considering to use `ListView` but the fact that each page contains static content too between the usercontrols is a drawback.

Can someone propose a way to do it?

Thanks.

**Solution (partially):**

Using @Sheridan's proposal i managed to achieve (partially) what i wanted by creating `DataTemplate`s in my `ResourceDictionary` and loading them dynamically from codebehind.

**DataTemplate (example)**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyUserControl1" DataType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
    <local:UserControl1 />
</DataTemplate>
```

**Usage in Page1 (example)**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="cC1Page1" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyUserControl1}" />
```

**Change ContentTemplate from Codebehind (example)**

```
this.cC2Page1.ContentTemplate = FindResource("MyUserControl1") as DataTemplate;
```

Now I have to see if the `DataBinding`s are working properly and find a way to add a new Page for the `UserControl`s tha does not fit inside the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, we tend to manipulate *data* rather than *UI controls*. By that I mean that we display our data either in a `UserControl`, or via a `DataTemplate`. Therefore, to *copy* some UI controls from one place to another, we actually just copy the data from one place to another and either display the same `UserControl` or rendered `DataTemplate` with the same data in that location.

For you scenario, I would recommend that you define a `DataTemplate` that includes your `UserControl` and then just apply that `DataTemplate` to a `ContentControl` in whichever page you want to display it in. Take this simple example:

In `Resources`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="YourDataTemplate" DataType="{Local YourDataType}">
    <!-- Define your UserControl here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you can display it like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding YourDataObject}" 
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource YourDataTemplate}" />
```

So in fact, all you need to duplicate is this last line and the WPF Framework will do the hard work of duplicating the related view.

Comment: Thanks @Sheridan i will try it. So, in codebehind i will just add and remove "Childs" to and from the `ContentControl`?

Comment: Ok, i get it. `ContentControl` gets a single piece of content of any type. So i just have to change the `ContentTemplate` from codebehind.